# JavaScript - While loop statement prints out multiple times

Tags: javascript

I am unable to print a single output statement when there is no match. At the moment, if there is no match (no number incl. in password) it will print out multiple times until it does find a match.

Could anyone take a look at my dilemma below please:

```
var password = "password1";
var i = 0;

function checkPassword(password) {
  if (password === "") {
    console.log("password cannot be empty");
  } else if (password.length < 8) {
    console.log("password should be at least 7 characters");
  } else {
    while (i < password.length) {
      if (password[i] == password.match(/[0-9]/g)) {
        console.log("found: " + password[i]);
      } else {
        console.log("not found");
      }
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This check in while loop makes no sense.

Comment: One of the most efficient ways is to place the log statement after the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var password = "password1";
var i = 0;

function checkPassword(password) {
  if (password === "") {
    console.log("password cannot be empty");
  } else if (password.length < 8) {
    console.log("password should be at least 7 characters");
  } else {
    var found = false;
    while (i < password.length) {
      if (password[i].match(/[0-9]/g)) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
      i++;
    }
    if(found) {
      console.log("found");
    } else {
      console.log("not found");
    }
  }
}
```

---

But, if you are only looking for a number in the string, you should better do it like this:

```
var password = "password1";

function checkPassword(password) {
  if (password === "") {
    console.log("password cannot be empty");
  } else if (password.length < 8) {
    console.log("password should be at least 7 characters");
  } else if(!password.match(/[0-9]{1,}/)) {
    console.log("password should contain at least one number");
  } else {
    console.log("okay");
  }
}
```

*Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7btt1axb/*

Comment: While the second code example works, when running your first code example in a snippet, at `if (password[i] != password.match(/[0-9]/g)) {` it always returns `not found` if the password has a number or not and is still not working.

Comment: Yes, wrote it too fast. It is fixed now.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for.. I love the simplicity of the code!

Comment: @StevenHanson and if you want to get real adventures you can do all the checks in a single `match` and simply print out the whole password requirements each time instead of telling the user 1 mistake at a time what they did wrong. If this is for a public app, that would be less frustrating to users as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
var password = "password1";

function checkPassword(password) {
  if (password === "") {
    console.log("password cannot be empty");
  } else if (password.length < 8) {
    console.log("password should be at least 7 characters");
  } else {
    var i = 0, found = false;
    while (i < password.length && !found) {
      if (password[i] == password.match(/[0-9]/g)) found = true;
      else i++;
    }
    if (found) {
      console.log("found: " + password[i]);
    } else console.log("not found");
  }
}
checkPassword(password);
```

Comment: There is no need to loop through each individual letter as `password.match(/[0-9]/g)` will detect any number in any position in the password and return an array with the matches and if no match is found `null` is returned, which is considered `false` in the context of the if statement.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. ssc-hrep3's answer is the way to go. I voted him.